# Mixing for-in and if-let in Swift

Tags: swift

Can I merge a for-in and if-let in one statement?

```
    for item in array {
        if let f = item as? NSDictionary {
            result.addObject(newFile(f))
        }
    }
```

`array` is made by a JSON, so I don't know if each item is a `NSDictionary` or not. I have to check.

I was looking for something like this:

```
for item as? NSDictionary in array {
 // code
}
```

Like Python or Ruby.

Comment: For what? to make it shorter? your code is clear and readable. Don't make life harder to other developer after you that tries to understand your logic :)

Comment: If that array is an array of dictionaries why do you need if let at all?

Comment: What are you trying to check? What type is `array`?

Comment: My question is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nickfalk is on the right track, but we can do better. His result unfortunately returns `[AnyObject]`, which you can't then call `newFile` with (I assume). But that's ok, we can get the rest of the way pretty easily.

What you want is partial map. That is to say, you want to map some (but possibly not all) of the elements of one list to another list (from `AnyObject` to `File`, if we can). So there must be some rule for choosing, and some rule for mapping. Optional let's us combine those. Let's call the function that does that `f`. Then its type is:

```
f: T->U?
```

So there's some magic function that will possibly convert `T` to `U`. We want to map with that. Sounds easy:

```
extension Array {
  func partialMap<U>(f: T->U?) -> [U] {
    var result = [U]()
    for x in self {
      if let u = f(x) {
        result.append(u)
      }
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

So now we've hidden all the nasty mutation and `var` and whatnot down deep where we don't have to look at it. We have a function that takes a mapping function from "something" to "maybe something else" and returns a list of "something elses that we could map."

Now everything is nice and immutable and reusable:

```
let result = array.partialMap { ($0 as? NSDictionary).map(newFile) }
```

Whoa there. What's that `map` in the middle? Well, `as?` returns `NSDictionary?`. When you `map` an optional, then if the optional is `None`, it returns `None`, otherwise it applies the function to the value and wraps it in `Some`. So this whole thing takes `AnyObject` and returns `File?` just like we wanted. One `partialMap` later we have our answer.

Comment: It would be nice to not return optional and filter out all non-compatible types out in your array extension. Then I can safely call `newFile` without unpacking the argument in it.

Comment: That's what this does. `newFile` is called with `NSDictionary`, not an optional. `partialMap` returns `[U]`, not `[U?]` or `[U]?`. If you wanted to turn `mapPartial` into `filter-things-I-can-convert`, then that's just `array.partialMap { $0 as? NSDictionary}`, which returns `[NSDictionary]`.

Comment: So obviously you could also use `array.partialMap { $0 as? NSDictionary }.map(newFilter)`, but that will require that you walk the list twice. Not a big deal if it makes the code clearer for you (and for long chains it can), but you can also do it in a single pass.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably just go for something like:

```
let result = array.filter() { $0 is NSDictionary }
```

If you need `result` to be an NSDictionary array, you can just cast it:

```
let result = array.filter() { $0 is NSDictionary } as [NSDictionary]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to reduce an `NSArray` to an array only containing `NSDictionary` filter is a very powerful tool. Create the appropriate filtering function:

```
func filterForNSDictionary(object: AnyObject) -> Bool{
    return object.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)
}
```

Then simply pass in you array and function to the `filter` function

```
let result = filter(array, filterForNSDictionary)
```

---

As @RobNapier points out my solution above will end up with a result array being of the type `[AnyObject]` this can of course easily be remedied:

```
let result = filter(array, filterForNSDictionary) as [NSDictionary]
```

This could be considered risky, if you force the array to be of the wrong type. `as [NSString]` (for instance9 would most likely blow up in your face down the line...

Rob's solution being pure awesome cleverness of course and @MattGibson delivering the perfect shorthand, while exposing me as an absolute beginner in this field.